# Find the first un-repeated character in a string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, string

What is the quickest way to find the first character which only appears once in a string?

Comment: Irrespective of language

Comment: are you talking about consecutive repetition, or simply if a character appears more than once in the string?

Comment: Isn't the very first character always the first that isn't repeated, since there's no characters for it to be a repeat of?

Comment: Since you asked for the "quickest way", You should have picked Mark's answer, as Ryan's will become very slow for long strings due to doing many scans of the `repeated` list

Comment: Aah... Found a solution. Posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549192/1903116. The key idea here, is to **process the data backwards.**

Comment: _character_ = Unicode character, string element (char) or grapheme (What the user means when he says "character")?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see that people have posted some delightful answers below, so I'd like to offer something more in-depth.

### An idiomatic solution in Ruby

We can find the first un-repeated character in a string like so:

```rb
def first_unrepeated_char string
   string.each_char.tally.find { |_, n| n == 1 }.first
end
```

How does Ruby accomplish this?

### Reading Ruby's source

Let's break down the solution and consider what algorithms Ruby uses for each step.

First we call `each_char` on the string. This creates an enumerator which allows us to visit the string one character at a time. This is complicated by the fact that Ruby handles Unicode characters, so each value we get from the enumerator can be a variable number of bytes. If we know our input is ASCII or similar, we could use `each_byte` instead.

The `each_char` method is [implemented like so:](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_2/string.c#L8484-L8488)

```c
rb_str_each_char(VALUE str)
{
    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(str, 0, 0, rb_str_each_char_size);
    return rb_str_enumerate_chars(str, 0);
}
```

In turn, `rb_string_enumerate_chars` [is implemented as:](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_2/string.c#L8437-L8466)

```c
rb_str_enumerate_chars(VALUE str, VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE orig = str;
    long i, len, n;
    const char *ptr;
    rb_encoding *enc;


    str = rb_str_new_frozen(str);
    ptr = RSTRING_PTR(str);
    len = RSTRING_LEN(str);
    enc = rb_enc_get(str);


    if (ENC_CODERANGE_CLEAN_P(ENC_CODERANGE(str))) {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += n) {
        n = rb_enc_fast_mbclen(ptr + i, ptr + len, enc);
        ENUM_ELEM(ary, rb_str_subseq(str, i, n));
    }
    }
    else {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += n) {
        n = rb_enc_mbclen(ptr + i, ptr + len, enc);
        ENUM_ELEM(ary, rb_str_subseq(str, i, n));
    }
    }
    RB_GC_GUARD(str);
    if (ary)
    return ary;
    else
    return orig;
}
```

From this we can see that it calls `rb_enc_mbclen` (or its fast version) to get the length (in bytes) of the next character in the string so that it can iterate the next step. By lazily iterating over a string, reading just one character at a time, we end up doing just one full pass over the input string as `tally` consumes the iterator.

Tally is then [implemented like so](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_2/enum.c#L977-L999):

```c
static void
tally_up(VALUE hash, VALUE group)
{
    VALUE tally = rb_hash_aref(hash, group);
    if (NIL_P(tally)) {
        tally = INT2FIX(1);
    }
    else if (FIXNUM_P(tally) && tally < INT2FIX(FIXNUM_MAX)) {
        tally += INT2FIX(1) & ~FIXNUM_FLAG;
    }
    else {
        tally = rb_big_plus(tally, INT2FIX(1));
    }
    rb_hash_aset(hash, group, tally);
}


static VALUE
tally_i(RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST(i, hash))
{
    ENUM_WANT_SVALUE();
    tally_up(hash, i);
    return Qnil;
}
```

Here, `tally_i` uses `RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST` to call repeatedly to `tally_up`, which updates the tally hash on every iteration.

### Rough time & memory analysis

The `each_char` method doesn't allocate an array to eagerly hold the characters of the string, so it has a small constant memory overhead. When we `tally` the characters, we allocate a hash and put our tally data into it which in the worst case scenario can take up as much memory as the input string times some constant factor.

Time-wise, `tally` does a full scan of the string, and calling `find` to locate the first non-repeated character will scan the hash again, each of which carry O(n) worst-case complexity.

However, tally also updates a hash on every iteration. Updating the hash on every character can be as slow as O(n) again, so the worst case complexity of this Ruby solution is perhaps O(n^2).

However, under reasonable assumptions, updating a hash [has an O(1) complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214594/237931), so we can expect the average case amortized to look like O(n).

---

### My old accepted answer in Python

You can't know that the character is un-repeated until you've processed the whole string, so my suggestion would be this:

```
def first_non_repeated_character(string):
  chars = []
  repeated = []
  for character in string:
    if character in chars:
      chars.remove(character)
      repeated.append(character)
    else:
      if not character in repeated:
        chars.append(character)
  if len(chars):
    return chars[0]
  else:
    return False
```

Edit: originally posted code was bad, but this latest snippet is Certified To Work On Ryan's Computer™.

Comment: Erm... first_non_repeated_character('aaab') == 'a'

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I had in mind. I somehow was thinking that there could be some other quicker solution.Can you tell me the order of this algorithm?

Comment: This algorithm is O(n), and won't use much memory as few characters will be stored in either `chars` or `repeated` at any given time. That makes it decent-ish in my book. However, if you have a seriously long string to check, the algorithm could be massively parallelized with little extra code or worry.

Comment: I think your code works correctly now. A note about performace: testing if an element is in a list is O(m) where m is the length of the list. With a long unicode string with lots of different repeated characters, the `character in repeated` will become slow as `repeated` contains more and more elements.

Comment: Can this be optimized to use only one array instead of the 2 arrays you have used, chars and repeated ?

Comment: The worst-case running time of this algorithm is O(n^2) if `chars` and `repeated` are arrays. Worst case memory usage is O(n) extra memory. I'd hardly call that "decent-ish" performance. Consider the string `abcdefghijkla`. Every character gets added to `chars`, meaning that a linear search of `chars` takes longer and longer. Massive parallelism won't help with an O(n^2) algorithm. Using a hash table will make the running time O(n), although it still requires O(n) extra space.

Comment: It isn't a true O(n^2) runtime unless you assume an unlimited number of potential characters. The largest set of characters I know of is Unicode, which according to this page[1] contains 234,803 designated code points. The runtime is O(n^2) so long as n<234,803; but that's not the same as having a o(n^2) algorithm runtime, because once you run out of characters, the runtime stops growing exponentially.

[1] http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/char-count.html

Comment: To check is a `character` is in `chars` array is also a complexity. Though the system does it natively, but it is `O(n)`

Comment: I suspect this algorithm isn't `O(n)`. It'll be `O(a*n)`, the `a` is ranging from 0 to n. So worst will be `O(n*n)`. But if the string happen to be quite repeating, `a` could be even smaller than `1`.

Answer (score 32):

It has to be at least O(n) because you don't know if a character will be repeated until you've read all characters.

So you can iterate over the characters and append each character to a list the first time you see it, and separately keep a count of how many times you've seen it (in fact the only values that matter for the count is "0", "1" or "more than 1").

When you reach the end of the string you just have to find the first character in the list that has a count of exactly one.

---

Example code in Python:

```
def first_non_repeated_character(s):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    l = []
    for c in s:
        counts[c] += 1
        if counts[c] == 1:
            l.append(c)

    for c in l:
        if counts[c] == 1:
            return c

    return None
```

This runs in O(n).

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a heap based data structure such as a minimum priority queue.  As you read each character from the string, add it to the queue with a priority based on the location in the string and the number of occurrences so far.  You could modify the queue to add priorities on collision so that the priority of a character is the sum of the number appearances of that character.  At the end of the loop, the first element in the queue will be the least frequent character in the string and if there are multiple characters with a count == 1, the first element was the first unique character added to the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another fun way to do it. Counter requires **Python2.7** or **Python3.1**

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def first_non_repeated_character(s):
...     return min((k for k,v in Counter(s).items() if v<2), key=s.index)
...
>>> first_non_repeated_character("aaabbbcddd")
'c'
>>> first_non_repeated_character("aaaebbbcddd")
'e'
```

Comment: Does this gracefully handle a string with no single-occurrence characters? http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min suggests there might be an issue with an empty iterable passed in.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, raises a `ValueError`. I guess that's a fairly graceful way to handle the empty sequence, as it doesn't make sense to ask for the first non repeated character in `""`

Comment: No, I mean how will it handle `first_non_repeated_character('aabbccdd')`?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, well the output isn't specified in that case either. I guess it could return None or "", but ValueError should still be acceptable

Answer (score 3):

Lots of answers are attempting O(n) but are forgetting the actual costs of inserting and removing from the lists/associative arrays/sets they're using to track.

If you can assume that a char is a single byte, then you use a simple array indexed by the char and keep a count in it.  This is truly O(n) because the array accesses are guaranteed O(1), and the final pass over the array to find the first element with 1 is constant time (because the array has a small, fixed size).

If you can't assume that a char is a single byte, then I would propose sorting the string and then doing a single pass checking adjacent values.  This would be O(n log n) for the sort plus O(n) for the final pass.  So it's effectively O(n log n), which is better than O(n^2).  Also, it has virtually no space overhead, which is another problem with many of the answers that are attempting O(n).

Comment: If you can assume that a char is a single byte, then the "lists/associative arrays/sets" are also going to be O(1).

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: Anything like an array or hash table will be O(1), but some of the answers here are using trees and linear lists which have typical access times of O(log n) to O(n). So the final algorithms are O(n log n) or even O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

Counter requires **Python2.7** or **Python3.1**

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def first_non_repeated_character(s):
...     counts = Counter(s)
...     for c in s:
...         if counts[c]==1:
...             return c
...     return None
... 
>>> first_non_repeated_character("aaabbbcddd")
'c'
>>> first_non_repeated_character("aaaebbbcddd")
'e'
```

Comment: I think that your algorithm will fail with "aaaebbbcddd" and still say that 'c' is the first non repeated character.

Comment: @Peter M, I'm curious why you would think that. It's easy enough to try and see that it works!

Comment: . *slaps head* Its because I was thinking terms of C arrays and not Python Array/Lists or however you want to describe it.  Oops.  My Bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it in C.   This operates in O(n) time with no ambiguity about order of insertion and deletion operators. This is a counting sort (simplest form of a bucket sort, which itself is the simple form of a radix sort).

```
unsigned char find_first_unique(unsigned char *string)
{
    int chars[256];
    int i=0;
    memset(chars, 0, sizeof(chars));

    while (string[i++])
    {
        chars[string[i]]++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (string[i++])
    {
        if (chars[string[i]] == 1) return string[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning i, it should return string[i], in that second while loop.

Comment: `0xFF` is a valid char! You should promote the return type to `int` and return -1 in case there is no unrepeated character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring a solution proposed earlier (not having to use extra list/memory). This goes over the string twice. So this takes O(n) too like the original solution.

```
def first_non_repeated_character(s):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        counts[c] += 1
    for c in s:
        if counts[c] == 1:
            return c
    return None
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that the dictionary accesses are really a worst case of O(1) so I suspect this solution isn't really O(n).

Comment: @PeteFordham The dictionary access really is worst case O(1). The size of the dictionary is bounded by the size of the character set, so the worst-case cost of constructing the dictionary does not scale with the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a Ruby implementation of finding the first nonrepeated character of a string:

```
def first_non_repeated_character(string)
  string1 = string.split('')
  string2 = string.split('')

  string1.each do |let1|
    counter = 0
    string2.each do |let2|
      if let1 == let2
        counter+=1
      end
    end
  if counter == 1 
    return let1
    break
  end
end
end

p first_non_repeated_character('dont doddle in the forest')
```

And here is a JavaScript implementation of the same style function:

```
var first_non_repeated_character = function (string) {
  var string1 = string.split('');
  var string2 = string.split('');

  var single_letters = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < string2.length; x++) {
      if (string1[i] == string2[x]) {
        count++
      }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
      return string1[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(first_non_repeated_character('dont doddle in the forest'));
console.log(first_non_repeated_character('how are you today really?'));
```

In both cases I used a counter knowing that if the letter is not matched anywhere in the string, it will only occur in the string once so I just count it's occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby:

(Original Credit: Andrew A. Smith)

```
x = "a huge string in which some characters repeat"

def first_unique_character(s)
 s.each_char.detect { |c| s.count(c) == 1 }
end

first_unique_character(x)
=> "u"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def first_non_repeated_character(string):
  chars = []
  repeated = []
  for character in string:
    if character in repeated:
        ... discard it.
    else if character in chars:
      chars.remove(character)
      repeated.append(character)
    else:
      if not character in repeated:
        chars.append(character)
  if len(chars):
    return chars[0]
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Other JavaScript solutions are quite c-style solutions here is a more JavaScript-style solution.

```
var arr = string.split("");
var occurences = {};
var tmp;
var lowestindex = string.length+1;

arr.forEach( function(c){ 
  tmp = c;
  if( typeof occurences[tmp] == "undefined")
    occurences[tmp] = tmp;
  else 
    occurences[tmp] += tmp;
});


for(var p in occurences) {
  if(occurences[p].length == 1)
    lowestindex = Math.min(lowestindex, string.indexOf(p));
}

if(lowestindex > string.length)
  return null;

return string[lowestindex];

}
```

Comment: String.indexOf() searches through the string from left to right, you can consult Mark Byers'answer. You can look at this codepen also:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/awHlq

Answer (score 0):

in C, this is almost [Shlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) (not quite O(n!) but more than 0(n2)).

But will outperform "better" algorithms for reasonably sized strings because O is so small. This can also easily tell you the *location* of the first non-repeating string.

```
char FirstNonRepeatedChar(char * psz)
{
   for (int ii = 0; psz[ii] != 0; ++ii)
   {
      for (int jj = ii+1; ; ++jj)
      {
         // if we hit the end of string, then we found a non-repeat character.
         //
         if (psz[jj] == 0)
            return psz[ii]; // this character doesn't repeat

         // if we found a repeat character, we can stop looking.
         //
         if (psz[ii] == psz[jj])
            break; 
      }
   }

   return 0; // there were no non-repeating characters.
}
```

edit: this code is assuming you don't mean *consecutive* repeating characters.

Comment: This algorithm does in fact operate in O(n^2).  It'd be an interesting exercise to design an O(nlogn) algorithm for the problem.

Comment: Edit: @Mark Byers has an O(n) algorithm.  So simple.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but 0 is orders of magnitude larger for Mark Byers' algorithm.  You can do a lot of re-scanning the same area of memory in the time it takes to do a single new.

Comment: While it undoubtedly does use dynamic allocation in Python, there's no real need for it to do so -- the sizes of the structures involved are both bounded by the size of the character set (though that's not much help if it's UCS-4 Unicode).

Comment: Your note about consecutive characters is because something like `aab` would return the second `a` instead of `b` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation in Perl (version >=5.10) that doesn't care whether the repeated characters are consecutive or not:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $word(@ARGV)
{
  my @distinct_chars;
  my %char_counts;

  my @chars=split(//,$word);

  foreach (@chars)
  {
    push @distinct_chars,$_ unless $_~~@distinct_chars;
    $char_counts{$_}++;
  }

  my $first_non_repeated="";

  foreach(@distinct_chars)
  {
    if($char_counts{$_}==1)
    {
      $first_non_repeated=$_;
      last;
    }
  }

  if(length($first_non_repeated))
  {
    print "For \"$word\", the first non-repeated character is '$first_non_repeated'.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    print "All characters in \"$word\" are repeated.\n";
  }
}
```

Storing this code in a script (which I named `non_repeated.pl`) and running it on a few inputs produces:

```
jmaney> perl non_repeated.pl aabccd "a huge string in which some characters repeat" abcabc
For "aabccd", the first non-repeated character is 'b'.
For "a huge string in which some characters repeat", the first non-repeated character is 'u'.
All characters in "abcabc" are repeated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution in ruby without using `Array#detect` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732593/457819)). Using `Array#detect` makes it too easy, I think.

```rb
ALPHABET = %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)

def fnr(s)
  unseen_chars    = ALPHABET.dup
  seen_once_chars = []
  s.each_char do |c|
    if unseen_chars.include?(c)
      unseen_chars.delete(c)
      seen_once_chars << c
    elsif seen_once_chars.include?(c)
      seen_once_chars.delete(c)
    end
  end

  seen_once_chars.first
end
```

Seems to work for some simple examples:

```rb
fnr "abcdabcegghh"
# => "d"

fnr "abababababababaqababa"                                    
=> "q"
```

Suggestions and corrections are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public static String findFirstUnique(String str)
    {
        String unique = "";

        foreach (char ch in str)
        {
            if (unique.Contains(ch)) unique=unique.Replace(ch.ToString(), "");
            else unique += ch.ToString();
        }
        return unique[0].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [*Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) one might write this:

```
string = "conservationist deliberately treasures analytical";

Cases[Gather @ Characters @ string, {_}, 1, 1][[1]]
```

> ```
> {"v"}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet code in JavaScript

```
var string = "tooth";
var hash = [];
for(var i=0; j=string.length, i<j; i++){
    if(hash[string[i]] !== undefined){
        hash[string[i]] = hash[string[i]] + 1;
    }else{
        hash[string[i]] = 1;
    }
}

for(i=0; j=string.length, i<j; i++){
    if(hash[string[i]] === 1){
        console.info( string[i] );
        return false;
    }
}
// prints "h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach here.
scan each element in the string and create a count array which stores the repetition count of each element.
Next time again start from first element in the array and print the first occurrence of element with count = 1

```
C code 
-----
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char t_c;
    char *t_p = argv[1] ;
    char count[128]={'\0'};
    char ch;

    for(t_c = *(argv[1]); t_c != '\0'; t_c = *(++t_p))
        count[t_c]++;
    t_p = argv[1];
    for(t_c = *t_p; t_c != '\0'; t_c = *(++t_p))
    {
        if(count[t_c] == 1)
        {
            printf("Element is %c\n",t_c);
            break;
        }
    }

return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

input is = aabbcddeef output is = c

```
char FindUniqueChar(char *a)
{
    int i=0;
    bool repeat=false;
    while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (a[i] == a[i+1])
      {
        repeat = true;
      }
      else
      {
            if(!repeat)
            {
            cout<<a[i];
            return a[i];
            }
        repeat=false;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return a[i];
}
```

Comment: Your code checks for consecutive characters, which is different from repeated characters on the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in C# with complexity of n.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SomethingDigital
{
    class FirstNonRepeatingChar
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            String input = "geeksforgeeksandgeeksquizfor";
            char[] str = input.ToCharArray();

            bool[] b = new bool[256];
            String unique1 = "";
            String unique2 = "";

            foreach (char ch in str)
            {
                if (!unique1.Contains(ch))
                {
                    unique1 = unique1 + ch;
                    unique2 = unique2 + ch;
                }
                else
                {
                    unique2 = unique2.Replace(ch.ToString(), "");
                }
            }
            if (unique2 != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(unique2[0].ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No non repeated string");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach...we could have a array which will store the count and the index of the first occurrence of the character. After filling up the array we could jst traverse the array and find the MINIMUM index whose count is 1 then return str[index]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

#define No_of_chars 256

//store the count and the index where the char first appear
typedef struct countarray
{
    int count;
    int index;
}countarray;

//returns the count array
    countarray *getcountarray(char *str)
    {
        countarray *count;
        count=new countarray[No_of_chars];
        for(int i=0;i<No_of_chars;i++)
        {
            count[i].count=0;
            count[i].index=-1;
        }
        for(int i=0;*(str+i);i++)
        {
            (count[*(str+i)].count)++;
            if(count[*(str+i)].count==1) //if count==1 then update the index
                count[*(str+i)].index=i; 

        }
        return count;
    }

    char firstnonrepeatingchar(char *str)
    {
        countarray *array;
        array = getcountarray(str);
        int result = INT_MAX;
        for(int i=0;i<No_of_chars;i++)
        {
            if(array[i].count==1 && result > array[i].index)
                result = array[i].index;
        }
        delete[] (array);
        return (str[result]);
    }

    int main()
    {
        char str[] = "geeksforgeeks";
        cout<<"First non repeating character is "<<firstnonrepeatingchar(str)<<endl;        
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Function:

This c# function uses a HashTable (Dictionary) and have a performance O(2n) worstcase.

```
private static string FirstNoRepeatingCharacter(string aword)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();            

        for (int i = 0; i < aword.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(aword.Substring(i, 1)))
                dic.Add(aword.Substring(i, 1), 1);
            else
                dic[aword.Substring(i, 1)]++;
        }

        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            if (item.Value == 1) return item.Key;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Example:

> string aword = "TEETER";
>
> Console.WriteLine(FirstNoRepeatingCharacter(aword)); //print: R

Answer (score 0):

I have two strings i.e. 'unique' and 'repeated'. Every character appearing for the first time, gets added to 'unique'. If it is repeated for the second time, it gets removed from 'unique' and added to 'repeated'. This way, we will always have a string of unique characters in 'unique'. 
Complexity big O(n)

```
public void firstUniqueChar(String str){
    String unique= "";
    String repeated = "";
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(!(repeated.contains(str.subSequence(i, i+1))))
            if(unique.contains(str.subSequence(i, i+1))){
                unique = unique.replaceAll(Character.toString(ch), "");
                repeated = repeated+ch;
            }
            else
                unique = unique+ch;
    }
    System.out.println(unique.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is an elegant way to find the first unique character within a string using the new features which have been introduced as part as Java 8.  This solution uses the approach of first creating a map to count the number of occurrences of each character.  It then uses this map to find the first character which occurs only once.  This runs in O(N) time.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

// Runs in O(N) time and uses lambdas and the stream API from Java 8
//   Also, it is only three lines of code!
private static String findFirstUniqueCharacterPerformantWithLambda(String inputString) {
  // convert the input string into a list of characters
  final List<String> inputCharacters = Arrays.asList(inputString.split(""));

  // first, construct a map to count the number of occurrences of each character
  final Map<Object, Long> characterCounts = inputCharacters
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(s -> s, counting()));

  // then, find the first unique character by consulting the count map
  return inputCharacters
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> characterCounts.get(s) == 1)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution with o(n) time complexity.

```
public void findUnique(String string) {
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] chatArr = new int[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        Character ch = string.charAt(i);
        if (chatArr[ch] != -1) {
            chatArr[ch] = -1;
            uniqueList.add(ch);
        } else {
            uniqueList.remove(ch);
        }
    }
    if (uniqueList.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No unique character found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("First unique character is :" + uniqueList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good thing array access in Java (taking your name as a hint) is checked. How do I tell a return value of `0` meaning _no character appeared just once_ from a return value of `0` meaning _the first  character appearing only once is `0`_? (What is the advantage of invoking `contains()` to control `remove()`?)

Comment: Updated answer based on your comments

Comment: Almost all a commentator should hope for. Now, what happens when you try to have "rats live on £ no evil star" processed?

Answer (score 0):

I read through the answers, but did not see any like mine, I think this answer is very simple and fast, am I wrong?

```
def first_unique(s):
    repeated = []

    while s:
        if s[0] not in s[1:] and s[0] not in repeated:
            return s[0]
        else:
            repeated.append(s[0])
            s = s[1:]
    return None
```

## test

```
(first_unique('abdcab') == 'd', first_unique('aabbccdad') == None, first_unique('') == None, first_unique('a') == 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Question : First Unique Character of a String
This is the simplest solution.

```
public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";

        firstUniqCharindex(a);
    }

    public static void firstUniqCharindex(String a) {
        int[] count = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            count[a.charAt(i)]++;
        }
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (count[a.charAt(i)] == 1) {
                index = i;
                break;
            } // if
        }
        System.out.println(index);// output => 8
        System.out.println(a.charAt(index)); //output => P

    }// end1
}
```

IN Python :

```
def firstUniqChar(a):
  count = [0] * 256
  for i in a: count[ord(i)] += 1 
  element = ""
  for items in a:
      if(count[ord(items) ] == 1):
          element = items ;
          break
  return element


a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";
print(firstUniqChar(a)) # output is P
```

Using Java 8 :

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";

        Map<Character, Long> map = a.chars()
                .mapToObj(
                        ch -> Character.valueOf((char) ch)

        ).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(), 
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println("MAP => " + map);
        // {G=2, i=5, n=2, a=2, P=1, r=1, o=1, t=1, j=1, y=1}

        Character chh = map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1L)
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        System.out.println("First Non Repeating Character => " + chh);// P
    }// main

}
```

Answer (score -1):

how about using a suffix tree for this case... the first unrepeated character will be first character of longest suffix string with least depth in tree..

Answer (score -1):

Create Two list -

1. unique list - having only unique character .. UL
2. non-unique list - having only repeated character -NUL

```
  for(char c in str) {
    if(nul.contains(c)){
     //do nothing
    }else if(ul.contains(c)){
      ul.remove(c);
      nul.add(c);
    }else{
       nul.add(c);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Another answer(Might not be so efficient but a kind of approach that we can try in c++; Time complexity:O(n) Space complexity:O(n)).

char FirstNotRepeatingCharInString(char *str)
{
    //Lets assume a set  to insert chars of string
    char result;
    multiset<char> st;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        st.insert(str[i]);  
    }
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(st.count(str[i]) <=1){
            result = str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are insert and count in multiset guaranteed to be O(1)?

Comment: Typical multiset implementations have inset at O(log n).

Answer (score -1):

If the char array contains repeating characters contiguously (eg. "ggddaaccceefgg) then following code would work:

```
char FirstNonRepeatingChar(char* str)
{
     int i=0;
     bool repeat = false;
     while(str[i]!='\0')
     {
       if(str[i] != str[i+1])
       {
         if(!repeat)
           return(str[i]);
         repeat = false;
       }
       else
        repeat = true;
      i++;
    }
return ' ';
}
```

Comment: I had put a disclaimer on the top for that if you care to note that.

Answer (score -1):

```
  /**
   ** Implemented using linkedHashMap with key as character and value as Integer.
   *
   *  Used linkedHashMap to get the wordcount. 
   *  This will return a map with wordcount in the same order as in the string.
   *  
   *  Using the iterator get the first key which has value as 1.
   *  
   */

package com.simple.quesions;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class FirstNonRepeatingChar 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a = "theskyisblue";
        System.out.println(findNonRepeating(a));
    }

    // Function which returns the first non repeating character.

    public static char findNonRepeating(String str)
    {
       // Create a linked hash map 

        LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap();
        if(str == null)
            return ' ';
        else
        {

        // function to get the word count 

            for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
            {
                char val = str.charAt(i);
                if(val != ' ')
                {
                    if(map.containsKey(val))
                    {
                        map.put(val,map.get(val)+1);
                }
                else
                {
                    map.put(val, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    // get all the keys in the set and use it in iterator.
    Set keys = map.keySet();
    Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
    char key;
    int val;

    // get the first key which has value as " 1 " .

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
         key = (Character) itr.next();
         val = (Integer) map.get(key);
         if(val == 1)
             return key;
    }

    return ' ';
}
```

}

Comment: For future users and for clarity of your answer, can you please explain you method instead of simply a post of code. This will help facilitate understanding and learning instead of simply providing a code block.

Answer (score -2):

The following is a solution in C++:

```
 char FirstNotRepeatingChar(char* pString)
 {
     if(pString == NULL)
         return '\0';

     const int tableSize = 256;
     unsigned int hashTable[tableSize];
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i<tableSize; ++ i)
         hashTable[i] = 0;

     char* pHashKey = pString;
     while(*(pHashKey) != '\0')
         hashTable[*(pHashKey++)] ++;

     pHashKey = pString;
     while(*pHashKey != '\0')
     {
         if(hashTable[*pHashKey] == 1)
             return *pHashKey;

         pHashKey++;
     }

     return '\0';
 }
```

I had a blog to discuss this problem at http://codercareer.blogspot.com/2011/10/no-13-first-character-appearing-only.html. Any comments will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Too much variables (memory usage)