# Finding the first non-repeated character of a string in O(n) using a boolean array?

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

My question is related to this earlier question

> [Find the first un-repeated character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285533/find-the-first-un-repeated-character-in-a-string).

In one of my interviews I was asked to write a function to determine the first unique character in a string in time O(n) using as extra space only a boolean array of length n.  That is, find the first non repeating letter in a string using only O(n) complexity and a bool array of length n.  Can some suggest how to solve it with bool array?

Comment: Do we know anything about the size of the alphabet the strings range over?

Comment: Are we allowed to mutate the input string?

Comment: I have a gut feeling this is not possible using the provided constraints. If solved it might be the best [minimal perfect hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function) known to man.

Comment: I agree with paislee, I don't think this is possible, unless you're allowed to use a boolean array that is at least twice the size of the alphabet.

Comment: Either the interviewer or interviewee is confused.  O(n) is asymptotic notation; it refers to the limit as n becomes arbitrarily large.  In that limit, n is arbitrarily larger than the size of the character set, in which case the question is trivial.

Comment: @Nemo, O(n) may apply only to the asymptote, but the restriction to a boolean array of size n must apply for all n, which makes this quite difficult for small n. What's your trivial solution?

Comment: @Aaron:  Ah, OK.  In that case I agree it's (probably) impossible.

Comment: If we didn't care about time, we could sort the data in place and find non-repeated characters. But I don't know how to find which one was first.

Comment: you can assume alphabets to be from a to z

Comment: yes we can mutate the input string

Answer (score 10):

Well, if the size of the character set is constant...  Say, for instance, 0-255...

Scan the string looking for character 0.

Then scan the string looking for character 1.

Then scan the string looking for character 2.

...

Finally, scan the string looking for character 255.

This takes 256*n operations which is O(n).

During each scan, if the character is unique, mark its position in the bitmap.  At the end return the character at the first marked position.  (Or just record the first unique character and its location using k + log(n) bits.  Use a hard-coded lookup table or whatever for very small n; otherwise, n bits is generous.)

Although somehow I suspect this is not what the interviewer had in mind.

Comment: Since the letter range was a to z only, I think this answer might would have worked.. thnks

Comment: Hehe, another `interview-question` about O(1) space and O(n) time complexity for finding repeated/non-repeated/even-frequent item in an array. Time for a wiki-post?

Comment: Why do you suspect the interviewer didn't have this in mind? Just curious

Comment: @0xc0de:  I guess I was assuming there is a more interesting/clever answer that I was missing.  If this is the best answer, it seems more like a trick question (and abuse of the big-O concept) than a meaningful interview puzzle, IMO.

Comment: 256 x n which is O(k\*n) which could sometimes be worse than O(n\*n) or O(n^2), this is such a tricky question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static void FirstNonRepeatingCharacters()
    {
        string s = "abbazccdde";
        var result = from item in s
                     group item by item into groupedItems
                     where groupedItems.Count() == 1
                     select groupedItems.Key;
        Console.WriteLine(result.First());                    
    }
```

C# implementation

Comment: That's an algorithmic question, you fail if you use any language-specific feature.

Comment: This implementation works, yet it fails because it doens't fit in the requirements: "in time O(n) using as extra space only a boolean array of length n", it doesn't fit because you use IGrouping and IGrouping is not a "boolean array of length n".

Answer (score 0):

**For Single Pass Solution**

Maintain 2 data structures:

1. Array / bitmap / hashtable for tracking the count of each character
2. LinkedHashMap to track the characters which have occured only once so far.

LinkedHashMap has

- O(1) insertion
- O(1) deletion
- O(1) search

  ```
  class Node
  {
    char data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
  };

  class LinkedHashMap
  {
          // This will keep the insertion order intact
          Node listHead;
          Node currentTail = listHead;
          HashTable<char, Node> charExistsMap;

      void Add(char ch) 
      {
          if(!charExistsMap.ContainsKey(ch)) 
          {
              // Add to both hashtable and linkedlist
              Node n = new Node(ch);
              n->next = null;
              n->prev = curentTail; // Added To List
              currentTail = n;
              charExistMap.Add(ch, n);
          }
          else 
          {
              // Remove from both hashtable and linkedlist
              Node n = charExistMap.Remove(ch);
              if(n->prev != null) 
              {
                  n->prev->next = n->next
                  listHead = n->next; // update head
              }
              if(n->next != null)
                  n->next->prev = n->prev;
           }
      }

      char GetFirstNonRepeatingChar()
      {
          return listHead->data;
      }
  ```

  }

After the original string is traversed, the head of the LinkedHashMap will contain the first character which is not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstUniqueChar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "ABxacd";

    test = test.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        int firstIndex = test.indexOf(test.charAt(i));
        int lastIndex = test.lastIndexOf(test.charAt(i));
        if (firstIndex == lastIndex) {
            System.out.println("First unique char of String " + test.charAt(i));
            break;
        }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), not O(n): you have O(n) iterations, and each iteration invokes O(n) operations indexOf and lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in two passes:

1st pass: create bool array of size 256 and for each char in the text mark the element of index int(that char). This takes O(n).

2nd pass: for each char in the text check if the corresponding array element is marked. If not then you found your answer. This also takes O(n).

Answer (score -2):

Have two boolean arrays, seenOnce and seenMany.
Loop over the string populate the arrays.
Loop over the string again checking if the character is in seenFirst but not in seenMany. If it is thats your first non-repeating character.

Here's some example code in python.

```
subject = "ttojxxlma"

seenOnce = [False for i in range(256)]
seenMany = [False for i in range(256)]

for c in subject:
    index = ord(c)
    if seenOnce[index] == False:
        seenOnce[index] = True
    else:
        seenMany[index] = True

for c in subject:
    index = ord(c)
    if seenOnce[index]==True and seenMany[index] != True:
        print(c)
        break
```

Ok that still uses too boolean array (or python lists =P). To use only one array you can have one array thats double the amount of characters. Instead of accessing the second array double the index and access the big one. But thats just messy.

Not sure if it can be done with less space.

Comment: I think the question specifically asks to do this with just one boolean array of length n, not two boolean arrays of length n.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure how you'd populate these arrays from the original string.  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Can you elaborate how to populate the arrays? this is not a linked list, so populating it may take o(n) for each addition