# how do I match a any repeating character using regexp?

Tags: go

I need to match any character that's repeated twice, for example:

```
"abccdeff"
```

Should match "cc" and "ff". In any other regex syntax, let's use Javascript as a quick example, I could do:

```
var str = "abccdeff";
var r = /([a-z]{1})\1/g
console.log(str.match(r))
```

Which returns

```
[ 'cc', 'ff' ]
```

But Go's regexp doesn't seem to allow that. Is it possible to do this in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since backreference is [not supported by re2](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html), you would need:

- either to use [another regex library](https://godoc.org/?q=pcre) (like [`glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre`](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre))
- or [code a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285561/6309) which does the analysis without regexp

Comment: Looks like the pcre library solves my problem. Thanks